# What was the plagiarised story published by Asimov’s?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In *[Asimov’s Galaxy](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9780385241205)*, there is a reprinted editorial from August 1985 on plagiarism that the afterword notes was inspired by a real case of plagiarism in a story in the eponymous magazine. The Good Doctor elected to name neither the story that turned out to be plagiarised, nor who was plagiarised, writing:

> AFTERWORD: Naturally, this essay was written because Shawna McCarthy had accepted and published a story which was recognized by a number of readers to be a plagiarism (though not a word-for-word one). I carefully refrained from naming the story or the author (though we will never buy a story from him again). When a reader wrote to us indignantly that this response was insufficient, I had to explain that it would be tricky to try to prove plagiarism in court, and that there might well be a countersuit for libel. Life can be hard, I'm afraid.

What was the story that inspired the editorial and what was the story it plagiarised?

Comment: Is this the same editorial referred to in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/277788/101407)?

Comment: Yes! But a different story (the one I’m asking about isn’t by Asimov)

Comment: Note:  The August 1985 [editorial in question](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v09n08_1985-08/page/n5/mode/1up)

Comment: Heh.  Someone sufficiently motivated could probably brute-force this.  There are [30 issues](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/seriesgrid.cgi?20321) of *Asimov's* edited by McCarthy that were published before May 1985, which is probably about as late as the editorial would have been written for an August publication date.  All we need to do is list stories by a male author, published in *Asimov's* between January 1983 and April 1985, who never appeared in *Asimov's* again after that. :)

Comment: Do we know if the plagiarist was a regular in Asimov's, or if this was his only appearance there?

Comment: @StanleyWebb we don’t, although my guess would be it’s more likely to be a first time author given that an author who had regularly written original stories is likely to be less at risk of trying something as stupid as plagiarism? [that’s assuming this was intentional not accidental plagiarism, which may be unwarranted as an assumption]

Comment: If we identify the story can we be sued for libel by the alleged plagiarist?

Comment: Surely not, because we aren’t proving or asserting it was plagiarised , but rather that it had sufficient similarity to some other work that readers wrote in and it was t reprinted and the author blacklisted, which is historical fact

Comment: I'm curious about the answer to this one because I was a devoted reader of Iasfm at that time (and had the time to keep up) so I certainly read that story

Comment: @asimovsgalaxyuk Well, the title of the question says directly that it's asking for a "plagiarised story". Maybe an "allegedly" should be edited into the title.

Comment: What's the standard for answering this question? Identifying a story by circumstantial evidence would be speculative and indirectly accuse a possibly innocent author of plagiarism.

Comment: Given the story prompted a stir of reader outrage at the time and was apparently well spotted and observed in fan lore, evidence from science fiction fandom (eg, from Zines) can show the nature of the incident as the allegations at the time indicated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawna_McCarthy is still alive. Maybe ask her

Comment: @DavidW Brute-force is not so simple here. I've found at least ten candidates (and there may be more). Asimov's had a tendency to encourage new and unknown writers, and inevitably many of them didn't make it and so didn't publish again.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez why not make an answer out of that? Maybe we can narrow it down from there.

Comment: @SQB I feel a bit uneasy about that. Most of them will be blameless, so it doesn't feel good to publicly question their integrity.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I'm only a bit more than 1/3 of the way through, and there are a lot more (16 so far) than I expected.  I have however identified 5 in particular that are more likely than the others; extrapolating to 15, that's a fair number to check, but not impossible.  The problem will be identifying the original story if it's not immediately obvious...

Answer (score 10):

It's worth reading the [essay](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v09n08_1985-08/page/n5/mode/2up). Plagiarism isn't always blatant. It can be subtle or accidental. Coincidences can look like plagiarism. Publishing plagiarized material is embarrassing and reflects badly on the magazine and its editors. Openly accusing an author of plagiarizing material can damage the career of an author who doesn't deserve it, with the risk of being sued and having to prove it. Authors and editors generally want to avoid even the appearance of plagiarism.

I also found [this 1976 interview with Isaac Asimov](https://www.depauw.edu/sfs/interviews/asimov41interview.htm) where he talks about the line between acceptable borrowing and plagiarism:

> ...the general feeling is that ideas are common property: if one SF writer thinks up something which is very useful, another may put it into his own words and use it freely. Nobody in SF is going to accuse any other person in SF of using his ideas; in fact, we borrow so generously that there's no way of telling whose idea it was originally. For instance, in my novel *The Caves of Steel*, it was very important to the plot to have moving sidewalks, with an elaborate system of side strips that enabled you to work up to the speed of the sidewalk or to work down to the surrounding, motionless medium. This had already appeared some years before in Heinlein's "The Roads Must Roll." Well, I borrowed it without any worry at all. I'm sure that Heinlein in reading my novel would have recognized his system, but who knows where he got it from? He never said anything. It'd be different if I used the details of his plot, if I worked up a story that was so like his that nobody could fail to see it—that's plagiarism. But just to use the idea and build your own plot or story about it—why, we do that all the time. And they do it from me, too—you know, they use the three laws of robotics—and they're welcome. I have no objection.

The magazine apparently received a number of letters from readers which they decided not to print, likely to avoid publicizing the incident and publicly accusing the author. They wanted to respond to these letters, to explain how it happened, but they couldn't get too specific without again accusing the author. So they published this essay, which should be viewed in part as a response to the incident and those letters. The last two columns of the essay can be read as an explanation of what happened, and what the magazine has done about it.

In this light, one story stands out as a likely candidate: [*Dèjá Lu*](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v08n11_1984-11/page/n125/mode/2up) by [Henry Clark](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?11447). The story is a good circumstantial fit:

1. It was published in November 1984. The essay was published in August 1985, and the letters column from the August issue mostly discusses the January 1985 issue, giving some clue to the publication lead time.
2. This was last work of the author published by the magazine (previous works are [1](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v03n10_1979-10/page/n177/mode/2up), [2](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v06n08_1982-08/page/n85/mode/2up), [3](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v07n03_1983-03/page/n117/mode/2up)). In fact he has no further credits in ISFDB until some childrens' books thirty years later. He apparently also wrote for *Mad* magazine and there's a [gap](https://madtrash.com/contributor/000566/) in his contributions covering this time period, for whatever that indicates.
3. [The story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42781) has never been reprinted.
4. I could only find one [letter](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v09n09_1985-09/page/n13/mode/2up?q=deja) which mentions the story, in the September 1985 issue, by a reader apparently trying to say something about every story in the issue:

   > "Deja Lu” by Henry Clark should become a classic — the P. D. Q. Bach of science fiction; plagiarism with humor is the sincerest form of flattery. Or something.

(Spoilers for [*Dèjá Lu*](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v08n11_1984-11/page/n125/mode/2up) follow.)

Reading the story, it's clear that it might have a plagiarism problem. *Dèjá Lu* is chock full of references to other stories, plagiarism is mentioned in the second sentence, and the title "Dèjá Lu" literally means [a feeling of having read something before](https://www.paranormality.com/deja_lu.shtml).

The story's conceit is that the narrator had something implanted in his brain which causes him to confuse fact and fiction. As he tells the story, he repeatedly includes bits from other stories. Many of these references are obvious, notorious, and don't affect the plot. The editors apparently felt okay with passing references like James Bond,  [Tralfamadorians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tralfamadore), and "To Serve Man". Some other borrowing is less obvious, however, and may have slipped past the editors. Then it was viewed as crossing the line once readers called their attention to it. Here are a few that I've identified:

1. The passage "It was on a bitterly cold and frosty morning during the winter of ’97 that I was wakened by a tugging at my shoulder...." (page 128 in the magazine) comes directly from [a Sherlock Holmes story](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/returnofsherlockholmes-270.html).
2. The line "As a young man I had resolved to forge in the smithy of my soul the uncreated conscience of my race." on page 129 is from a [James Joyce novel](https://www.robertrussellmagee.com/to-forge-meaning-in-joyce-s-portrai).
3. The alien name "Egtverchi" is from the James Blish novel [*A Case of Conscience*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Case_of_Conscience).
4. The term ["Polywater"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywater) is from some 1960s junk science. But the term "Ice-9" and the idea of a substance destroying the world's water supply comes directly from Vonnegut's [*Cat's Cradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_Cradle).
5. The idea of scaring away the aliens by telling them tall tales comes directly from a [*Twilight Zone* episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hocus-Pocus_and_Frisby) (acknowledged in the story).
6. A story referencing its own publication has been done at least once before: [*Don't Look Behind You*](https://archive.org/details/ellery-queens-mystery-magazine-v-009-n-042-1947-05-missing-pg-63-64-65-66/page/48/mode/2up) by Frederic Brown (skip to page 56 column 2 if you don't want to read the whole thing).

Comment: Huh... to me, it feels like an intentional borrowing of those phrases, since the idea of the story is that of unconscious plagiarism, but I suppose that Asimov and his company might be a lot more wary.

Comment: I’m sceptical because Déjà lu is a story that publicly announces its borrowing, which doesn’t meet the key criterion of a story that Shauna was embarrassed to have slip past her and regrets publishing. No one could accuse a story explicitly about intertextuality of plagiarism

Comment: If it had been a story like that, the Good Doctor would have responded with an essay like his essay  ‘Irony’ explaining how readers didn’t get the joke. The plagiarism has to not announce it’s a plagiarism to get an editorial like ‘Plagiarism’. This seems like a red herring

Comment: The plagiarism essay explicitly  states that works which make no secret they are a pastiche or borrowing are not plagiarism but fall under the category of fun. So a work advertising it is using other material is not plagiarism by that definition and this can’t qualify.

Comment: *If you copy from one text it's plagiarism; if you copy from many it's research.* This sounds like a well researched story rather than plagiarism. The P. D. Q. Bach being referred to (there are at least two) did exactly the same, "the last and least of the Bach family" the music is short sections of well known pieces tied together to make an entertaining but incoherent whole. This seems like someone has done the same with well known stories.